# React-Native/Expo Receiving ERROR 'null is not an object (evaluating 'match.localteam_name')

Tags: ios, json, react-native, fetch, expo

Here I am only running two API requests. The first one in the componentDidMount function works fine, but the second one labeled handleMatchFacts does not work. In short, Using React-Native I'm retrieving information from the API, mounting it to the page and then once the Touchablehighlight is clicked it is suppose to retrieve additional information from the API according to the 'id' that is passed in 'onPress'. I am able to console.log the json of the data in the second request, but for some reason when I setState with the new data and render it to the page in ListView, I get an error.

```
import React from 'react'

import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ListView, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native'


export default class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
  super();
  const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
  this.state = {
    matches: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
    matchFacts: ds.cloneWithRows([])
  };
  this.handleShowMatchFacts.bind(this)
}

  componentDidMount(){

    fetch("http://api.football-api.com/2.0/matches?match_date=27.04.2017&to_date=27.04.2017&Authorization=565ec012251f932ea4000001fa542ae9d994470e73fdb314a8a56d76")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(matches => {
      this.setState({
        matches : this.state.matches.cloneWithRows(matches)
      })
    })
  }

  handleShowMatchFacts = id => {
    console.log('match', id)
    return fetch(`http://api.football-api.com/2.0/matches/${id}?Authorization=565ec012251f932ea4000001fa542ae9d994470e73fdb314a8a56d76`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(matchFacts => {
      console.log('match facts', matchFacts)
      let selectedMatch = matchFacts;
         this.setState({
        matches : this.state.matches.cloneWithRows([]),
        matchFacts : this.state.matchFacts.cloneWithRows(selectedMatch)
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <Text 
      style={styles.header}>
      Todays Matches</Text>
      <ListView
          style={styles.matches}
          dataSource={this.state.matches}
          renderRow={(matches) => 
          <TouchableHighlight 
          onPress={() => this.handleShowMatchFacts(matches.id)}
          underlayColor="green"
          ><Text style={styles.item}> {matches.localteam_name} {matches.localteam_score} - {matches.visitorteam_score} {matches.visitorteam_name} </Text>
         </TouchableHighlight>
          }
        />
      <ListView
          style={styles.matches}
          dataSource={this.state.matchFacts}
          renderRow={(match) => 
          <Text style={styles.item}> {match.localteam_name} {match.localteam_score} - {match.visitorteam_score} {match.visitorteam_name} </Text>
          }

        />   

    </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer : {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20
  },
  header : {
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  matches : {
    marginTop: 20
  },
  item : {
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: 'green',
    marginBottom: 5,
    padding: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably seeing an issue because the second API request doesn't return an array, it returns an object. The `cloneWithRows` expects an array. Replacing this line

`matchFacts : this.state.matchFacts.cloneWithRows(selectedMatch)`

with

`matchFacts : this.state.matchFacts.cloneWithRows([selectedMatch])`

may help, depending on how you render this new data.

That's just a guess since I don't know what error you're receiving.